# Formal language inverse

Tags: formal-languages, terminology

How can you specify the "inverse" of a word, so:
let's say a word consists of a's and b's the language is:
$ww^{-1}$
the second word is the same as the first but every a is replaced by b and every b by a

Comment: You just specified it, though perhaps you should use different notation (invent one).

Comment: I'm not aware of any notation for that. Even if there is "standard" notation for it, it's not in common enough use that you can just use it without defining it.

Comment: How do you define your inverse if $|\Sigma| > 2$?

Comment: @Raphael. One might define the "inverse" of a word $w$ to be the result of applying a permutation $\sigma$ on the alphabet to the characters of $w$. Then for a language $L$ we could define $\sigma(L)$ to be the language resulting from the application of $\sigma$ to the words in $L$, leading to questions like, "given a (regular, context-free, ...) language $L$, under what conditions is $\{w\sigma(w)\mid w\in L\}$ also (regular, CF, ...)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're calling $w^{-1}$ is a special case of what's known as a *homomorphism*, where, informally speaking, we define a map $h$, from an alphabet $\Sigma$ to strings over an alphabet $\Gamma$ and then extend this in a natural way to maps of words. In your case, the map is particularly simple: $h(a)=b$ and $h(b)=a$. There's quite a bit known about such maps; for instance both regular and context-free languages are closed under homomorphisms.

(For what it's worth, your $ww^{-1}$ language isn't regular.)